# Only two spaces of indentation in JavaScript in RubyMine?

Tags: javascript, indentation, rubymine

Is there a way to configure [RubyMine 3.1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+3.1) to only use two spaces to indent JavaScript?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Which version of `RubyMine` are you using?

The [JetBrains site of reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/general-3.html) for v3.1 reads as follows:

```
Settings dialog -> Project settings -> Code style -> General -> Indent
```

> **Indent:**
>
> In this text box, specify the
>   number of spaces (or tabs if the Use
>   Tab Character check box is selected)
>   to be inserted for each indent level.

As for altering this specifically for Javascript, I don't see a possible solution - or at least not an easy one. You might be able to configure these *general* settings per file type, however. But I'm no expert in this field.

Comment: There are tabs for different languages in Project settings -> Code style -> General -> Tabs and Indents, including JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Newer Answer:

on OSX Mavericks with RubyMine 6.3

```
File -> Default Settings -> Code Style -> JavaScript
```

The fact that this isn't under preferences is infuriating.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer from Joe:

On OSX Mavericks with RubyMine 7.1.2

```
File -> Default Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Javascript
```

And change the indentation settings in the 'Tab and Idents' tab.

It's pretty similar from the Joe's Answer, just adding the Editor option.